# Save long innertext of specific XML node to a text file

Tags: c#, xml

I have XML files that are coming from a third party program containing Base64 string (2,000,000 characters)

I want to save the inner text of a specific node to a text file (about 70,000 characters), the problem is that I can't deal with this file as XML file because of the last line in the file. as I will show you now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<cProgramECUPackageOut xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                       ID="b0eb0c7e-a3de-4bc7-9e63-7a082f8a2bc5" 
                       Version="16.01" xmlns="cProgramECUPackageOut">
    <text1>N    </text1>
    <No>487382</No>
    <text2>128</text2>
    <Data1>21110107</Data1>
    <Data2>21554863</Data2>
    <!-- I Need the inner text of this node -->
    <DST2>W01TV0NvbnRlbnRdDQo....about 70,000 Char</DST2>  
.
.
.
</cProgramECUPackageOut>3345802116632N    20814620154201445546
```

As you can see the last line in the XML file has text after the last node that will give an error when reading files as XML. I tried to deal with the files as text, but it didn't copy the full inner text.

I tried this related threads, but didn't get the job done.

[How to get innertext in an XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946475/how-to-get-innertext-in-an-xml)

[Get XML Innertext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419669/get-xml-innertext)

[Regex + Remove all text before match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841129/regex-remove-all-text-before-match)

[Get text between two words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733888/get-text-between-two-words)

I am new to C#, but I did hard work in searching for an answer.

Comment: Read it as text first, trim out the data that's after the last XML closing tag, save as a temp file, then read in the temp file as XML?

Comment: Why OuterXml does not work for you?

Comment: I'm not 100%, but you might be able to use XmlTextReader to read up to the element you want, assuming the file is valid xml to that point.  Because it doesn't load the entire file you should be OK assuming you don't try to read the entire xml file.

Comment: I tried
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(XMLFileName);

and it gave me the Error

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov why should it ?! I just want the inner text. and the innertext not works too (maybe it is long)

Comment: I see - I completely misunderstood your question which have nothing to do with selecting of nodes in XML. You have invalid XML to start with and trying to read it as XML - clearly not going to happen. You can try to read it as document fragments instead...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Can You tell me the Best way to Do this with large text as this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found The answer for this question as "Adam V" Said

so I tried it and I want to share it

1- replace the last line in the XML File

```
        File.Copy(XMLFileName, XMLFileName2);
        string Filepath = File.ReadAllText(XMLFileName2); 
        string fakeEnd = "</cProgramECUPackageOut>";
         lastlineStr = File.ReadLines(XMLFileName2).Last(); // the last line in the XML file
        Filepath = Filepath.Replace(lastlineStr,fakeEnd);
        File.WriteAllText(newPath, Filepath, Encoding.Unicode);
```

2- Read file as XML Using:   XmlDocument to get the innertext

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(newPath);
        XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("DST2").Item(0);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(node.InnerText);
        DST2 = sb.ToString();
        File.WriteAllText(@"c:\textFile.txt", sb.ToString(), Encoding.Unicode);
```